# How to append to state array in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a state set as

```
const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);
```

I want to be able to append to the end of that state. I am currently trying

```
products.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.category === category) {
          setFilteredProducts([...filteredProducts, product]);
        }
      });
```

It it looping through the products array correctly. I can even log the product after the setFilteredProducts and it logs the correct ones I want. I am calling this with an onClick.

Comment: You're stacking up `setState` calls, instead create the new filtered array and then call `setState` once

Answer (score 5):

Find all the products you want to add:

```
const productsToAdd = products.filter(product => product.category === category)
```

Then append them

```
setFilteredProducts((currentFilteredProducts) => ([...currentFilteredProducts, ...productsToAdd]));
```

The issue with your example is that `filteredProducts` may get stale after the first iteration. `setFilteredProducts` will *not* run synchronously, and `filteredProducts` keep the original value, until the re-render happen.

Answer (score 1):

You would only append the last match to the existing `filteredProducts` array.

You can add all matches like so:

```
setFilteredProducts([...filteredProducts, ...products.filter((product) => product.category === category)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you do this in 2 steps:

Create an array of the new products you plan to add

```
let productsToAdd = [];

products.forEach((product) => {
    if (product.category === category) {
      productsToAdd.push(product);
    }
  });
```

Then combine the arrays and set state

```
setFilteredProducts([...filteredProducts, ...productsToAdd]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want what the ES6 built-in function does. You can rewrite your code to give you the the products that match the category like this:

```js
const filteringTheProducts = products.filter(product => {
    return product.category === category
})

setFilteredProducts(filteringTheProducts)
```

The result of the filtering will be the array of all the products that match that criteria.

Here is the documentation for .filter()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that `setFilteredProducts` doesn't immediately affect products. It's React's job to decide when to update the state. So when you loop over products, you'll probably ending up adding just the last item, because `filteredProducts` wasn't updated yet.
What you can do, is preparing an array of products to add:

```js
const productsToAdd = products.filter(product => product.category === category);
```

And then append them:

```js
setFilteredProducts([...products, ...productsToAdd]);
```